# How do I reverse this string in python?

Tags: python, string, reverse

I need to create a function that reverses a string.

Name your function reverse.
Call your function with the input string 'This is my string'. and assign the result to the variable my_string.
Print out my_string!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
def string_reverse(string_value):
    return string_value[::-1]

my_string = "This is my string"
print(string_reverse(my_string))
```

or you can simply do it this way:

```
my_string = "This is my string"
print(my_string[::-1])
```